# Javax @NotNull message print in Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a Poja class,

```
Class Emp{
@NotNull(message="id should not be null")
private int id;
@NotNull(message="name should not be null")
private String name;
//getter
//setter
}

class MyActionClass{
public getRequestForm(String inputJsonString){
//id is null in above inputJsonString
try{
  Emp empInput = MyConvertClass.jsonToObject(inputJsonString);
}
catch(Exception e){
system.println(e.getMessage())
}
}
```

}

Validation works fine and printing NullPiointerException. But I want to display the message in exception like **id should not be null** If id is null.
**name should not be null** if name is null.

How to do using javax.validation?

Comment: If "validation works fine", shouldn't you be getting e.g., a [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/validation/constraintviolationexception) instead of a `NullPointerException`? If yes, then note `ConstraintViolationException` has a set of `ConstraintViolation`s that you can query.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation